# Sentry & Laravel, getting users within a group. changing findAllUsersWithAccess to have pagination

Tags: laravel-4, bigdata, cartalyst-sentry

I'm trying to find all users w/ a specific permissions list in Sentry with laravel. The problem is that `Sentry::findAllUsersWithAccess()` returns an `array()`.

as stated in their github repository i pinpointed their code to be

```
public function findAllWithAccess($permissions)
{
    return array_filter($this->findAll(), function($user) use ($permissions)
    {
        return $user->hasAccess($permissions);
    });
}
```

right now, it gets all users and filter it out with users with permission list. the big problem would be when I as a developer would get the set of users, it'll show ALL users, i'm developing an app which may hold thousands of users and i only need to get users with sepcific permission lists.

With regards to that would love to use one with a `->paginate()` capability.

Any thoughts how to get it without getting all the users.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you override the findAllWithAccess() method and write your own implementation, which uses mysql where instead of array_filter().

I dont know your project structure and the underlying db schema, so all i can give you atm is the link to the eloquent documentation [Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations) (whereHas).

In case you dont know where to start: its always a good idea to look at the ServiceProvider (SentryServiceProvider, where the UserProvider, which holds the findAllWidthAccess() method, is registered). Override the registerUserProvider method and return your own implementation of the UserProvider (with the edited findAllWithAccess() method).

Hope that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can do pagination manually on arrays:

```
$paginator = Paginator::make($items, $totalItems, $perPage);
```

Check the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/pagination

Comment: the pagination is not the issue. the issue at hand is, its

1. fetching all data first
2. using php to filter accessess

when in reality what i need is 

1. to call the users with specific permission only

assuming i got alot of users, its not viable since it wont be scalable

Comment: But findAllWithAccess() doesn't returns an array of user objects?

Comment: it does return an array of user objects.. but check out my question,  it CALLS every user, then filter it.. rather than using a mysql query to filter it, it uses php logic. which i could not use.